# How many digits are in $125^{100}$?

Tags: number-theory

What I can think of thus far is that $125^{100} = (\frac{1000}{8})^{100} = \frac{1000^{100}}{2^{300}}$

I know that $2^{10} = 1024$ so $\frac{1000^{100}}{1024^{30}}$.

That's all I can figure out this far.

I was thinking to divide the numerator and denominator of $\frac{1000^{100}}{1024^{30}}$ by $1000^{30}$ and I think that would give me $\frac{1000^{70}}{1.024^{30}}$ but I'm not even sure if this is correct.

Can someone please help me solve this?

**Edit: How can I solve this without the use of logarithms?**

Comment: If I had a calculator available, I would just use logarithms!

Comment: what about $\log_{10}(125^{100})$ and logarithm rules (and a calculator for $\log_{10}(125)$)?

Comment: See https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-digits-of-a-number/

Comment: You don't need a calculator to answer how many digits has  $\log_{10}{100}$ or $\log_{10}{100}$, and so neither do you need it to calculate the integer part of $\log_{10}{125}$ or any other decimal logarithm

Comment: Haha yes sorry, I forgot to mention that I cannot use logarithms. I am working from a book and the problem states that I cannot use logarithms.

Comment: Here’s the [answer](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how+many+digits+in+125%5E100), just without the accompanying work.

Comment: $0.024$ is small enough, so $1.024^{30} \approx e^{0.024\times 30} = e^{0.72} < e < 10$. The denominator is bigger than $1$ but smaller than $10$. it will cut the number of digits of your number from $211$ (that of $1000^{70}$) by $1$. i.e. the number of digits of your number is $210$.

Comment: @user8290579: That is weird, given that the answer is essentially the logarithm of $5$ to an accuracy of one part in $300$ (scaled up by that same factor of $300$).

Comment: If you want to find how many digits a number has, as long as it has less than $10000$ digits, this may help $\longrightarrow$ https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2^{10}\approx 10^3$, so approximately,  $\frac {1000^{100}}{10^{90}} =\frac {100^{100}\cdot 10^{100}}{10^{90}}=100^{100}\cdot 10^{10}=10^{210}$...  So about $211$.

Comment: Thanks! I really like your answer and it made it simple to understand however, the exact answer is 210 and I wanted to know how to arrive exactly at 210.

Comment: You cannot do that approximation - the digit is off. ($2^{10} = 1024, and when there are lots of 1024 multiplied, it will affect the digits - the actual digits are 210 instead of 211

Comment: Yes it's a little over because of the smaller number in the denominator...

Comment: The $2^{10}$ approximation is especially useful for logarithms. That makes computing $\log 5$ trivial.

Comment: @JohnLou: I tend to remember $\log_{10} 2 = 0.30103$ pretty accurately; the palindrome makes it not too difficult to remember.  Then of course, $\log_{10} 5 = 1 - \log_{10} 2$.

Comment: Yeah I do the same, except I just stick with $0.3$ :)

Comment: @JohnLou: Also a palindrome (at least the part after the decimal point). :-)

Answer (score 2):

Calculate

$\log_{10}125^{100}$

$= 100\cdot \log_{10} (1000/8)$

$= 100\cdot(3-3\log_{10}2)$

$= 100\cdot(3-0.9030)$

$= 100\cdot(2.0970)$

$= 209.70$

Therefore number of digits $= [209.70]+1 = 210.$

Comment: OP has already said NOT to use logarithms.

Comment: Although you got the right answer using the method OP said not to use, note that it should be $3-3\log_{10}2$ NOT $3-2\log_{10}3$

Comment: @JohnLou yes I was just going to point that out, since $8 = 2^3 \neq 3^2$. Therefore our finally result should be $\approx 300\times 0.30102999566398119521373889472449$ which surprisingly is less than $209.7$.

Comment: Because it was less than $209.7$, I realised I made a mistake; I forgot to subtract $3\log 2$ from $1$. Now we multiply *that* result by $300$ and we get $\approx 209.691$. But we conclude that there really isn't much of a difference.

Comment: @JohnLou sorry, I did not pay attention at that thing. By the way i still calculated value of $3 \log_{10} 2$. I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

Any solution implicitly computes a logarithm ($\log_{10} 5$ is approximately the answer to this question divided by $300$), but one can correct Chris Custer's answer for the extra digit by recalling the tangentially logarithmic "rule of $72$": An interest rate of $2.4$ percent will double the principle after $72/2.4 = 30$ periods.  So $(2^{10})^{30}$ will approximately equal $2 \times 10^{90}$, rather than just $10^{90}$.  That cuts the number of digits from $211$ to $210$.

Comment: Oops: edited to correct a factor of $10$ to a factor of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

As you worked out, $125^{100}=\dfrac{10^{210}}{1.024^{30}}$, so it is enough to show $1<1.024^{30}<10$ to conclude there are $210$ digits. But the left inequality is obvious and as $1+x\leqslant e^x$, we get $1.024^{30}\leqslant e^{0.024\times 30}=e^{0.72}<e<10,\;$ so the right inequality holds true as well.

Answer (score 1):

Logarithm base 10 Scale will better answer your question.

**Range**                                    **Digits**

1-log(10)                                   1

log(10)-log(10^2)          2

log(10^2)-log(10^3)   3

log(10^3)-log(10^4)   4

log(10^n-1)-log(10^n)  n

I think you get the Idea.

Now for your number $$125^{100} = 5^{300}$$

$$\log_{10}{5^{300}} = 300 * \log_{10}{5} = 209.691$$

That means it is between 209 and 210. From the above table pattern, you can confirm there will be **210** digits.

Comment: OP edited the question to preclude (explicit) logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

For any natural number n the number of digits is $ 1+[log(n)]$ where $ [log(n)]$ stands for the integer part of $log(n)$

For $n=125^{100}$, 
 we get $$log(n)= 100 log(125)=209.6910013...$$

Thus the number of digits in $125^{100}$ is $210.$

Comment: OP said not to use logarithms.

Comment: Not using logarithms would turn the problem into a trial and error game. $2^3$ is approximately $10$ and .....

Answer (score 0):

For all $x$ we have 
$$125^{100} < 125^{x}128^{100-x}=5^{3x}2^{700-7x}$$

Making $700-7x=3x$ we get $x=70$ and hence 
$$125^{100} < 5^{210}2^{210}=10^{210}$$
[I could had compared these two numbers directly, but using the $x$ above shows how I figured out that 210 is the key].

Since the approximation above is very close, intuition tells us that $125^{100}$ should have 210 digits. But intuiton is not enough, we need to prove it. Since we showed $125^{100} <10^{210}$, to conclude that 
$125^{100}$ has 210 digits we need to show
$$125^{100} \geq 10^{209}$

Lets prove it
$$125^{100} \geq 10^{209} \Leftrightarrow \\
5^{300} \geq 2^{209} 5^{209} \Leftrightarrow \\
5^{91} \geq 2^{209}  \Leftrightarrow \\
5^{13} \geq 2^{29.86}$$

The last inequality holds since $5^{13}>2^{30}$, but I don't see any simple way of getting this without a calculator.